# Is it possible to collect all messages during transaction execution?

Tags: ui-automation, abap

We have two SAP systems. One of them call RFC function module on second side. This module, in turn, runs transaction. Transaction yields some messages (type 'I' and 'S') which impossible to detect on the caller side.

So, Is it possible to take those messages through RFC to caller side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the **call transaction** documentation

```
... MESSAGES INTO itab
```

**Effect**

Using this addition, all the messages sent during batch input processing are stored in an internal table itab of the type BDCMSGCOLL from the ABAP Dictionary.

So yes, if you call a transaction via **call transaction** statement, you can gather all messages with this addition.

Comment: oh, next time I will read documentation more carefully. Thank you!